# Binding to Chosen liszt:ready event

Tags: jquery, events, jquery-chosen

We are using jQuery Chosen plugin to convert the HTML `select` to a nice searchable list. What I am trying is to add a link at the bottom of list after the Chosen is ready (i.e. `liszt:ready` is triggered).

I can easily bind to `liszt:showing_dropdown` with the following code and it works just fine:

```
$("select").chosen().on("liszt:showing_dropdown", function(){
   console.log "List opened."
})
```

However, when I try to replace `liszt:showing_drop` with `liszt:ready` it doesn't work. I think this is normal because the `liszt:ready` triggers when `$("select").chosen()` gets executed.

Here is the excerpt from jquery.chosen.js which triggers the `liszt:ready` event:

```
...
this.results_build();
this.set_tab_index();
return this.form_field_jq.trigger("liszt:ready", {
  chosen: this
});
...
```

Could someone please guide me how to bind to `liszt:ready` event?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm not sure if it's the right way to do it but it works for me:

1. Listen to `liszt:ready` event
2. Apply chosen
3. Trigger `liszt:ready` manually

Listen to `liszt:ready` event:

```
$("select").on("liszt:ready", function(){
   console.log("Hey, I am ready!");
})
```

Then apply Chosen and trigger the `liszt:ready` manually

`("select").chosen().trigger("liszt:ready");`

Please let me know if there is some more appropriate way to achieve this.