# How to trigger ready event on JQuery chosen plugin?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to bind an liszt:ready event of my list, to be invoked once that the list has been initialized by chosen.
I follow the steps that [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14889466/binding-to-chosen-lisztready-event) are describing without any success.
This is my code:

```
 var initPreferredCollaboratorChosen = function () {
    $("#preferredCollaboratorChosenId").chosen({width: "95%"}).trigger("chosen:ready");
  };

var initListener = function () {
    $("preferredCollaboratorChosenId").on("chosen:ready", function(){
        alert("Hey, I am ready!");
    });
    initPreferredCollaboratorChosen()       
};
```

I try with "liszt:ready" instead "chosen:ready" as well.

Can anyone that has work with this plugin tell me how make it?.

Regards.

Comment: Please add your current code to the question by editing it.

Comment: @Huangism I already add the code

Comment: You're missing a `#` on this line - `$("preferredCollaboratorChosenId").on("chosen:ready", ...)` - to make it an ID selector.

Comment: Jumping Jesus!, I was so blind!. Thanks a lot and so sorry for the silly quesiton